# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}$ diverges?

I can see that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1} = \pm 1$. But I'm not sure if the divergence of the sequence is enough to conclude the divergence of the sum.

Comment: If the terms don't tend to $0$, there is no chance that the series converges.

Comment: @mrf That is not a rule I would endorse. I prefer: If you have a series where the sign alternates, it is almost always possible to take advantage of the cancellation between successive terms, with the net result that convergence improves considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is. Google "divergence test".

Comment: Alright. Since the limit of the sequence is $\pm 1$ and thus not equal to 0 the series diverges.

Comment: The limit of the sequence isn't $\pm 1$, it doesn't exist. But yes you are correct.

Comment: I see, the limit does not exist. Thank you!

Comment: Remember that even if the limit is 0 it doesn't necessarily mean the series converges. Think of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: If it converges, then $\lim a_n=0$; but if $\lim a_n=0$, it doesn't necessarily converge.

Comment: This is a typical example where mathematicians like to demonstrate how rigorous they are in applying their theorems. As a physicist I am not interested whether the sum is officially categorized as "divergent". It is more important whether the sum can be evaluated. Which is of course possible. There are many good ways to do so. In that sense, the sum is "convergent".

Comment: @M.Wind How on Earth would you consider that comment to be helpful?

Comment: @avid19 It is good for math students to know that the official notion of "divergence" of sums is sometimes just a matter of convention.

Comment: To @M.Wind apparently the sum $1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots=(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots$ "evaluates" to $0$. Wait? It is also $1-(1-1)-(1-1)-\cdots$ so it also "evaluates" to $1$! Therefore $0=1$ and we can forget about all of physics, economy et cetera, because we can multiply anything with either $1$ or $0$ without changing anything!!!!!!! There are occasions, where we can attach a meaningful value to a divergent sum (such as principal values of improper integrals), but one needs to tread with care, when doing that. You are, of course, welcome to display your ignorance whenever you feel that way.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Don't be silly. You know very well that the meaningful result for your sum is $1/2$. This can be derived by means of  resummation, or by using a convergence factor.